# FusedLocationProviderClient always reports LocationAvailability false

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I have an app which has been live for a couple of years now, but lately, I've been getting reports about the location system not functioning properly.
I have tracked the issue down to the `LocationCallback.onLocationAvailability(availability: LocationAvailability?)`. it is always called with `availability.isLocationAvailable = false`

The description indicates that it being false, means that i cannot count on getting any locations from the other function `LocationCallback.onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?)` but the results tick in fine, and the position seems to be correct enough.

Can someone tell me if I can simply disregard the `isLocationAvailable = false` and just use the location results as they are, without taking any risks of getting false readings or or low accuracy or such?

I've tried with different settings for the LocationRequest, and there's no issue with any of them - except that the availability still gets called with false. The results themselves are fine.

Permissions are in place fair and square, I've also tried with `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` only, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` only and both on.
Location are enabled on the devices.

Did something change about the inner workings of the FusedLocation system in the last few weeks? It's worked perfectly for years now?

#### Code:

```
var locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = 10000
        fastestInterval = 5000
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY 
    }
```

When initializing and starting the location updates i use the following snip:

```
val locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
val task: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
task.addOnSuccessListener { locationSettingsResponse ->
    locationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
}
```

And with this LocationCallback:

```
val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
        locationResult ?: return
        if (locationResult.locations.isNotEmpty()) {
            val location = locationResult.locations[0]
        }
    }
    override fun onLocationAvailability(availability: LocationAvailability?) {
         availability?.isLocationAvailable          <-- This is always false!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is caused by new Google Play services update (version 21.30.16).

See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198176818

As per Sep 9, 2021 they say:

> We have temporarily rolled back some of the logic around
> isLocationAvailable() and you should note behavior returning to normal
> over then next 24 hours or so.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I wanted to hear: I was right all along :-)

Comment: There's more in that issue log from google that probably is worth reading: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198176818#comment37 - which arguably renders that status of no value.

Comment: At least it gives a hint of what to expect. F.x. you do get a call with `true` or `false` when the user enables/disables location from settings. Which is very important. But currently, you get `false` in both cases: not acceptable.
Well; hopefully, they'll have the update out soon.

Comment: But now all of our customers think it's our fault and lose faith in our systems... still broken a week later!

Comment: Update: It is still not fixed as of Play Services release 21.33.14, even though it was promised to be solved "in 24 hours"

Comment: Still not fixed...

Comment: Not Fixed till now !!!

Answer (score -2):

Your issue may be down to the updated GooglePlay policy regarding user location. The GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation), which came into force a few years ago, states that a user's location is [personally identifiable information](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/key-definitions/what-is-personal-data/), so the user's consent is required now before you can use this data.

This just means that adding ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION / ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest permissions is not enough. You will need to request permission from the user at runtime.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for more information on requesting location permissions at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, the permissions are in place fair and square. That of course means the runtime permissions also.
The issue is `onLocationAvailability(availability: LocationAvailability?)` callback. App-users have different options when location is available or not, and when the callback always tell me that it's not available, it is very difficult to provide clear feedback to the app-user.
My best try to remedy this is to rely on the `onLocationResult`'s: If they start coming in, location-based features can be enabled in the app, and if they don't, I must disable those.